# Why is order of data items reversed while creating a pandas series?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python and pandas so please bear with me. I tried searching the answer everywhere but couldn't find it. Here's my question:

This is my input code:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30], list)
```

The output is:

```
1     1
2     2
3     3
1    10
2    20
3    30
dtype: int64
```

Now, my question is why the "list" is coming before the first list specified while creating the series? I tried running the same code multiple times to check if the series creation is orderless. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Python Version:
Python 3.6.0
Pandas Version:
'0.19.2'

Comment: The second argument is for specifying the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you omit `index` which specify first column called `index` - so `Series` construction now is:

```
#dont use list as variable, because reversed word in python
L = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
s = pd.Series(data=[1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30], index=L)
print (s)
1     1
2     2
3     3
1    10
2    20
3    30
dtype: int64
```

You can also check [Series documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jezrael. That was silly of me. I confused series with dataframe and was expecting to see a two dimentional series like structure.